# Trying to hide and show menu items on action bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have looked through the questions on stack overflow and can't find the solution.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.themenu, menu);
    MenuItem   item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings);
    MenuItem item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_save);
    item.setVisible(isdown);
    item2.setVisible(isdown);
    return true;
}
```

This sets my menu items to visible (item1 and item2). the onclick works fine

```
public void inflateTextarea() {
    if(isdown == true) {
        isdown = false;
        LinearLayout tl = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.content);
        tl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ScaleAnimation scale =  new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 0, 1);
        scale.setFillAfter(true);
        scale.setDuration(500);
        tl.startAnimation(scale);
    }
}
```

Then this sets my isdown boolean to false. on stack people say that the onPrepareOptionsMenu should fire everytime I click but this is not the case.
I am able to hide one menu item on the onclick function

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings: 
            Log.v("Log:","edit_item pressed");
            return true;
    }
}
```

But I have multiple menu items that I need to hide and others that I want to show.
how can I go about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Its not enough to change the `isDown` variable. You have to call the `setVisible()` method every time you want to change the visibility. That method does more than just setting a boolean value, so just changing a boolean value will not do.

After changing the `isDown` value to false, you need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` which will re-launch the menu by calling `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` again.

Try this code for making the menu items unvisible:

```
...
isdown = false;
invalidateOptionsMenu();
...
```

Comment: yes I know that, but as i read the  onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { is supposed to fire everytime a menu item is clicked and THAT would work. I cant set the visibility unless I have Menu menu in the function, so that is where I am having a problem

Comment: I see. Edited post to cover this.

Comment: where do i add the invalidateOptionsMenu() method?

Comment: Anywhere within the activity after you change the value of isDown to false

Comment: nvm found it. i had to add a suppression for new api so i put the invalidation in its own function just incase. thank you

Comment: `invalidateOptionsMenu();` requires API 11. also to hide/show one item i don't think its good option to invalidate whole options menu!

Answer (score 11):

Try this,

```
private Menu menu=null;
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.note_menu, menu);
    this.menu=menu;
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
menu.findItem(R.id.menuChartNoteEdit).setVisible(isdown);
menu.findItem(R.id.menuChartOpenNote).setVisible(isdown);
}
```

When you want to hide menu at any where, after executing `onCreateOptionsMenu()`
then just change value for `isdown` and repeat this code,

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings).setVisible(isdown);
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_save).setVisible(isdown);
```

Comment: i heard the onPrepareOptionsMenu was supposed to be better, do you know what the difference is?

Comment: ok so now i can put my menu.find item in any function in my class?

Comment: yes, find Menu Item in any where on your class and hide/show..!, Are you check that?

Comment: i will try it out if it works will up vote thank you so much give me a few hours

Comment: both worked but the other answer by invalidating the menu is more efficient thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your FragmentActivity

```
public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
    if(isLeftMenuOpened()) return false;
    return super.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, menu);
}
```

Method FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel creates menu for all attached fragments. You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have a menu with two items, first: save item, second: edit item. I wanted when I came in to edit, at first "save item" had been hidden, and when I click "edit item", "save item" was shown.

So:

1. declare an item in public
2. set value to it in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`
3. set visibility to `isHidden()`
4. then every where I wanted, set visibility to `isVisible()`

Public region:

```
MenuItem saveItem;
```

onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail_products, menu);
    saveItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_detail_product_save);
    saveItem.setVisible(isHidden());
}
```

Where i want:

```
saveItem.setVisible(isVisible());
```

Finally it works as I wanted.